# Tests for ranked nominal data

Tags: dataset, categorical-data

I badly need help with the following problems.

In my questionaire I asked respondents to name the three most important priorities (in order of importance) in connection with a specific area of life. They were instructed they could name their priorities in a few words or max a short sentence. I coded their answers into one word categories. (e.g. "lot of money", "financial security" etc. were coded simply as Money) So I have ranked nominal data. I also had them complete an attitude scale and I have demographic data too. What stat tests could I use to answer the following questions:

1. Is there a connection between certain priorities named in the first place (e.g. money) and the size of the settlement they live in (I had 8 settlement size categories). In other words, I might ask : Are respondents who live in small villages (size category) more likely to have "Money" ranked as their first priority?
2. Are respondents who scored low on certain variables of the attitude scale more likely to have certain prioroties (like Money) ranked first, second or third?